# Android test exception:class not found Error Failed resolution of: Lorg/powermock/reflect/Whitebox;

Tags: java, android, android-testing

1. trace info

`com.sprd.linkturbo.tests.testWifiQosParams#TC_SmartLink_WifiQosParamsSetAndGetLostPackets_007: FAILURE (1ms) stack= java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/powermock/reflect/Whitebox; at com.sprd.linkturbo.tests.testWifiQosParams.TC_SmartLink_WifiQosParamsSetAndGetLostPackets_007(testWifiQosParams.java:37) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50) at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:52) at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17) at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.FailOnTimeout$CallableStatement.call(FailOnTimeout.java:148) at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.FailOnTimeout$CallableStatement.call(FailOnTimeout.java:142) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox`

2. AndroidManifest.xml

   ```
    <!-- We add an application tag here just so that we can indicate that
         this package needs to link against the android.test library,
         which is needed when building test cases. -->
    <application>
         <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
    </application>

    <!--This declares that this app uses the instrumentation test runner targeting
         the package of com.android.deskclock.  To run the tests use the command:
         "adb shell am instrument -w com.android.deskclock.tests/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    -->
    <instrumentation android:name="androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
                     android:targetPackage="com.sprd.linkturbo"
                     android:label="Tests for LinkTurbo."/>
   ```
3. Android.bp

   ```
   android_test {
        name: "SmartLinkTests",

        srcs: ["src/**/*.java"] + ["src/**/*.iml"],

        libs: [
            "android.test.base",
            "android.test.mock",
            "android.test.runner",
            "telephony-common",
            "radio_interactor_common",
            "com.unisoc.sdk.common",
            "platform-robolectric-3.6.2-prebuilt",
            "powermock-libs",
            "platform-byte-buddy-1.8.10-prebuilt",
            "platform-byte-buddy-agent-1.8.10-prebuilt",
            "platform-objenesis-2.6-prebuilt",
            //"LinkTurbo",
            //"uniframework"
         ],
         //sdk_version: "current",

         certificate: "platform",

         platform_apis: true,

         manifest: "AndroidManifest.xml",

         static_libs: [
             "mockito-target-minus-junit4",
             "platform-test-annotations",
             "truth-prebuilt",
             "frameworks-base-testutils",
         ],


         jacoco: {
            include_filter: ["com.sprd.linkturbo.*"],
         },


         instrumentation_for: "LinkTurbo",
    }
   ```

Comment: Which version of powermock are you using ?